# Solve expression with iterative method in Python

Tags: python, loops, coordinates, iteration

I'm new with Python, and started to work on a Coordinate Conversion program. The problem is that I can't find an iterative method to solve one of the expressions.

Expressions:

```
N = a / math.sqrt(1 - (e2 * (math.sin(phi))**2))

phi = math.atan((Z / math.sqrt((X**2) + (Y**2))) * ((1-e2) * (N / N + hei)**-1))
lam = math.atan(Y / X)
hei = (math.sqrt((X ** 2) + (Y ** 2))) / math.cos(phi)
```

Here, **a** and **e2** are constants.

The user is supposed to introduce the values of **X**, **Y** and **Z** and obtain **phi**, **lam** and **hei**. But, given that **N** is a function that depends of **phi**, it is necessary to create a loop, making **hei** = 0 in the second equation as an initial value, in order to procure a first approximation for **phi**. However, I don't know how to end that cycle when **phi** has reached a certain value (for instance, when 9 or more of the decimals of **phi** are equal to the previous value in the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break the loop based on the difference between the value of `phi` in the previous loop and that in the current loop, i.e. if the difference is smaller than `10^(-9)`.